# How can I block/reject doc, docx containing macro on my mail server?

Tags: postfix, malware

I'm wondering if it is possible to block/reject emails with *.doc* or *.docx* containing macro?

Is there any solution for `postfix` to be used in order to reject this kind of attachments?

Today I just received file which is type of ransomware - containing macro:

Meanwile I have cheked with `olevba.py`

```
olevba 0.46 - http://decalage.info/python/oletools
Flags        Filename                                                         
-----------  -----------------------------------------------------------------
OpX:MASIHB-- /home/user/Desktop/490141.doc
===============================================================================
FILE: /home/user/Desktop/490141.doc
Type: OpenXML
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VBA MACRO ThisDocument.cls 
in file: word/vbaProject.bin - OLE stream: u'VBA/ThisDocument'
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/03ed8927e9af6357133afc3bd78f84b56e00977f062dd27d7fc4ec65eba1c104?environmentId=100

That will be a great thing if it is possible to achieve.

**Edit:** As this is security relevant, I'm adding this here: Please see the below comment that one should block `docm` as well.

Comment: Note that `docx` cannot run macros. To block macros that use the new office file format, you should block the `docm` extension.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible via [SpamAssasin](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/FrontPage) for example, which is

> a mature, widely-deployed open source project that serves as a mail filter to identify Spam. SpamAssassin uses a variety of mechanisms including header and text analysis, Bayesian filtering, DNS blocklists, and collaborative filtering databases. SpamAssassin runs on a server, and filters spam before it reaches your mailbox.

Either write your own plugin, which checks for the existence of macros inside these files ([some common tips for writing plugins](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/PluginWritingTips)), or, maybe the better alternative, try something [like this](https://github.com/JonathanThorpe/spamassassin-vba-macro) (and contribute back improvements and/or bug fixes). I'm not using the later, so can't judge on the quality.

Comment: I will check that one, forgot to mention that I'm also using spamassassin so that can be useful combination.